# Visual Studio 2015 issue. 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio

I have installed visual studio 2015. I am making new web form project in Visual C#. As all the functionality like register and login is there but it is not working in my case.I have also commented above the line where error is generated.I am getting following error in code when i try to register a user.

**Below Error is generated**

> **An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code**
>
> **Additional information: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 52 - Unable to locate a Local Database Runtime installation. Verify that SQL Server Express is properly installed and that the Local Database Runtime feature is enabled.)**

**Code is given below.**

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin;
using Owin;
using WebApplication1.Models;

namespace WebApplication1.Account
{
    public partial class Register : Page
    {
        protected void CreateUser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var manager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
            var signInManager = Context.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationSignInManager>();
            var user= new ApplicationUser() { UserName = Email.Text, Email = Email.Text };
            //error is generated in below line
            IdentityResult result = manager.Create(user, Password.Text);

            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                // For more information on how to enable account confirmation and password reset please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320771
                //string code = manager.GenerateEmailConfirmationToken(user.Id);
                //string callbackUrl = IdentityHelper.GetUserConfirmationRedirectUrl(code, user.Id, Request);
                //manager.SendEmail(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>.");

                signInManager.SignIn( user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);
                IdentityHelper.RedirectToReturnUrl(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"], Response);
            }
            else 
            {
                ErrorMessage.Text = result.Errors.FirstOrDefault();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well the error message seems reasonably clear: "Unable to locate a Local Database Runtime installation. Verify that SQL Server Express is properly installed and that the Local Database Runtime feature is enabled."

Comment: Check the connection string.

Answer (score 0):

in Web.Config, check `<connectionStrings>` tag. make sure that the server is accessible and you have the right credentials.